# Gladiator scientist

Tags: story-identification

I read a sci-fi book back in the 70's which (I think) had an educated man/scientist who fought on different worlds in gladiatorial contests. I would say this book could have been written in the 50/60's. I don't think it was the 70's as most of the books I bought in the early 70's came second hand from jumble sales.
UPDATE:
I think perhaps I'll revise the word Gladiator. The character fought, but it may not be in the sense of an arena. As far as I can remember he was definitely a professor or someone who was highly educated. I'm thinking he fought off-world.

Update: Although I thought the story was identified, It isn't the one. Could this please be viewed and suggestions made. Thanks

Comment: I can't honestly remember. It was a long time ago, but I think he was a Professor. What he was fighting for I don't know. Sorry.

Comment: Sounds a bit like Doc Savage.

Comment: Wish it was Doc Savage as I'd remember it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The fighting was bull-fighting? As a demonstration to catch the interest of the rulers of the Galactic Empire?

Comment: Sorry Tonny, It wasn't bull-fighting. As little memory I have of the story it was definitely a combative spectacle the main character was involved in.

Comment: @Otis - OP says that this isn't the one; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83074/gladiator-scientist#comment180055_83250

Comment: @Valorum, oops -- yes, I missed the OP's second comment for the answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

"[Planet of the Damned](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1469260719)" by Harry Harrison sounds very much like what you are describing.
The main hero can very well be described as gladiator scientist, he wins a planet wide series of competitions from chess to fencing and everything in between, then goes on a mission to prevent war between two planets.

Comment: I thought I'd lost this story for good. But that's the one. Thank you.

Comment: There is one more novel from the same universe, "The planet of no return", pretty good read too.

Comment: @Kevin You can accept the answer by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: Please take a look at the update to my story identification request user14111. This wasn't the story, although initially I thought it could have been, but the main character in Planet of the Damned (which I'm reading) isn't the professor/gladiator/fighter of my memory of the story I read in the 70's.

Answer (score 2):

Pohl's Gladiator-at-Law? But I think he was a lawyer... ISFDB entry [here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1873) .

Comment: Hi Organic Marble. It sounds close but it isn't the one. The main character (the Professor/Scientist) was the gladiator. That was the juxtaposition of the character. A clearly intelligent man engaged in gladiatorial combat. I aslo think he fought off-world as well. Gladiator-at-Law takes place on this planet and the main character is not the gladiator. Thank you for suggesting this though as I'm going to buy it.